# PyDrive get only my files and shared with me files. Python

Tags: python, file, pydrive

Sorry for my english. I use pydrive for work whith google drive api. I want get list of files. I do it like this:

```
  return self.g_drive.ListFile({'q': 'trashed=false'}).GetList()
```

this return me list of files. But it list contains delete files. I think `'q': 'trashed=false'` it get only exist files, not in the bucket.

How i can get only exist files and files shared with me

Comment: Could you share the reference that you are using? Blog, tutorial or documentation where you got above.

Comment: @Nabin yes, i use documentation https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html

Comment: Try the **sharedWithMe** as mentioned in answer and see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `trashed=false` and query to get shared files is:
**sharedWithMe**
Also there is **no concept of bucket** in google drive

Query to use:

```
{'q': 'sharedWithMe'}
```

**EDIT**

**I still believe trashed=false should work**

Work around:

There must be a better way but a trick is to do the following:

```
list_of_trash_files = drive.ListFile({'q': 'trashed=true'})
list_of_all_files = drive.ListFile({'q': ''})
final_required_list = set(list_of_all_files) - set(list_of_trash_files)
```

Comment: thanks for answer. This query `{'q': 'sharedWithMe'}` i get only shared whith me files. I want get all MY FILES and shared whith me files, not trashed files

Comment: I think __{'q': ''}__ should give everything.

Comment: `{'q': ''}` yes, it give everythng and trashed files too( I dont need trashed files

Comment: in my question i get all files whith this query `{'q': 'trashed=false'}` and still i have list with deleted files

Comment: See the edit section, also you may be missing something as, trashed=false should be correct way. Look closely

Comment: as an option =) Thanks!